# How to add class files to a Maven2 project

Tags: maven-2, classpath

So I'm working on a java project (an exitsing java project that uses maven2, not mine). Everything works fine. 
I add a new class to the source directory.

I do `mvn compile` and get success.
I then do `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="package.NewClass"

and get `classNotFoundException`.

It does compile the new file, and I can see the NewClass.class in the right directory
with the other classes. So I don't get the classNotFoundException. Do I need to make any changes to the pom.xml?

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the complete Stacktrace ?

Comment: solved.. sorry guys, I misspelled the package name... Thanks for your help! 
At least now I know that Maven automatically takes care of these things without the need of touching the pom.xml file. thanks maven!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="package.NewClass"
```

---

**Resources :**

- [Mojohaus.org - exec plugin](http://mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) see java section.